# JQuery finding next biggest/smallest value

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I have to validate input field on the specific way:
This value must be divisible by proof value (can be integer or float). If there is an integer as result - OK, if the result is float - find the next smalles and biggest that can be divisible by this proof value.

I have following code at the Moment:

```
$("#calc").click( function(){
 var rlaenge = $("#rlaenge").val(); // is allways an integer
 var zEins = $("#zEins").val();
 var zZwei = $("#zZwei").val();
 var typeMath = <?php $_SESSION['typeMath']; ?>; // can be integer or float
 var erg = (parseFloat(rlaenge) - ((( parseFloat(zEins) + parseFloat(zZwei) ) / 2) * parseFloat(typeMath) )) / 2;
 var rlaengeCheck = rlaenge/typeMath;
 if (/^[0-9 ]+$/.test(rlaengeCheck)) {
  $("#result").value(erg);
 } else {

 //here the situation with findig off next biggest/next smallest  

 }          

});
```

I don't have any Idea how to build such one issue with JavaScript.

I will be very grateful for any help with this case.

Alex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you can do this so:

```
rest = x % k;
base = x - rest;
next_devidable = base + k;
prev_devidable = base;
```

OLD

use `Math` methods

The `floor()` method rounds a number DOWNWARDS to the nearest integer, and returns the result

The `ceil()` method rounds a number UPWARDS to the nearest integer, and returns the result.

then check devision then ++, -- the value if check not passed

Comment: If i'm right, ceil() and floor() rounds the floats upward/downwards. But what i need is to find the next value (integer) of rleange which can be divided by typeMath. rleange is always an integer and typeMath cab be both - integer or float.

It's something like "for" or "do" loop with $count in PHP.

Comment: yes, you are right, in your else statement you have the floats

Comment: Of course, but i need not just the next smallest/biggest integer, but the next one who can be divided by typeMath... And it's can be 5th one. Or 100th...

Comment: ok,then do only increment|decrement recursively until you find the next devisionable number

Comment: you are welcome ) I've edited the answer, added a possible solution without ++,--